# Detect if user verified their email?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-firebase

Using React Native Firebase, I'm giving users of the application the option to verify their email by pressing a button.

Once the button is pressed a verification email is sent. Is there any way to detect if the user has verified their email? I'm aware of the bool property in the authenticated user object, the issue is, the object doesn't update if the user has clicked the link and verified their email. This change is only detected if the user signs out of the application and back in.

Is there any way to "refresh" the user object once the link in the email has been pressed and the user object has changed in the Firebase database?

Verification function:

```
export const verifyEmail = () => {
  auth().currentUser.sendEmailVerification();
};
```

useEffect:

```
const [user, setUser] = useState(auth().currentUser);

useEffect(() => {
  const subscriber = auth().onAuthStateChanged(setUser);
  return subscriber;
}, []);
```

Comment: IMHO, wrong hook. useEffect only triggers when the component mounts, unmounts, or gets updated. You may need a custom hook there, hard to say without knowing more about your overall program logic.